# Magento: "Products Ordered" report - how to show child products of configurable product?

Tags: magento, product, configurable

When I create a "Products Ordered" report in Magento, configurable products show up as a single product, where the sales of all child products were summed up.

How can I modify this behaviour, so that - additionally - the child products are shown and their sold quantities?

The used version is Magento 1.6.2.

Comment: works for 1.9.3 as well. please note that this is very resource intensive if you have a lot of orders

Answer (score 8, accepted):

millejano from #magento-de helped me out and allowed me to post this answer:

Create a rewrite for or copy /app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php to local.
In *addOrderedQty()*, change the line

```
->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
```

to

```
->where('e.type_id = ?', 'simple')
```

You're done. Instead of the summed up configurable product, you will now see the underlying simple products in every report and even on the dashboard.

Original post by millejano: https://gist.github.com/3149637/

Comment: Great elegant solution, why the hell is there n standard option for this!?

Comment: I needed the same thing for Magento 2. The solution is very similar, but the field name and table alias have changed: ->where('order_items.product_type = ?', 'simple')